# Rendering in Aptana Different than in a Static Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, aptana3

I am experimenting with developing a primitive web interface using Aptana Studio 3, and when I run the site from Aptana as an internal server in either IE or Firefox, the page renders as I expect.  In contrast, when I open the same HTML page in a browser (i.e. not running it through Aptana), it displays incorrectly (e.g. modal dialog appears at the bottom of the page rather than as modal when I click a button).

I tried different "meta" compatibility commands at the top of the HTML code to see if I could duplicate how Aptana opens the site.  I am not sure if JS and JQuery need to be run as a server or if this is an indication of a bug in my code.  If it is a requirement to run JS, JQuery, and bootstrap in a server as Aptana does, any guidance on how to duplicate what Aptana is doing in a standalone offline fashion would be sincerely appreciated.

**Note:** This is a for a class assignment.  The assignment is unrelated to JQuery and Javascript; rather it is on UI design patterns and software engineering.  The reason I am using JS and JQuery is I thought this assignment would be a good opportunity to become more familiar with those tools.

Comment: As a note, when I run the site through GIthub hosting, the site appears the same as it does in Aptana.  This makes me think the site does need to be run on a server to display properly.  Any guidance on why that is would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most standard browsers, many jQuery features do not render/appear correctly if they are not run inside a web server.  When entering debug or run mode in Aptana, it is in the background starting a local web server.  If you want a free web based server, I recommended using the "rawgit" feature bundled with Github; this is what I ended up using.  For more information, see here:

https://rawgit.com/